# Reference for the renormalization of a scalar field's mass

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, resource-recommendations, renormalization

There are a couple of interesting lectures by Leonard Susskind online, and in the [first lecture on Supersymmetry & Grand Unification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6srShxBCrk) he explains renormalization. His example is the mass renormalization of a scalar field, and he uses a couple of dimensional analysis tricks to get his results (around 35:00). It's a nice lecture that makes you feel you understand the topic better, but at the same time it is a lot of hand waving. I'm trying to write up a bit on renormalization, along his line of argument, but I'm confused about a lot of small details.

For starters, he omits a lot of factors of $\pi$ and $2$, but OK, I can live with that. I think he skipped doing an integral when calculating the one loop diagram, but I'm not sure. Then I'm confused about the different diagrams were a particle goes from $A\rightarrow B$ without any loops or branches. Which one is called the propagator: the summed one, the naked one, the naked one with an explicit mass "$\times$"? How is it related to mass? I think I understand the physics, but the terminology is confusing to me.

Instead of asking a half-dozen confused questions, I'm looking for a reference, a book or a review, that explains the mass renormalization for a scalar field in a pedagogical way but without skipping the technicalities. I'd strongly prefer something citable (I'm hesitant to quote youtube in my thesis ;-)).

Comment: (The first few sections of) chapter 9 of Ryder's book 'Quantum Field Theory'  is what I used for renormalization of a real scalar field, and it's pretty OK. There are a lot of technicalities. You may also want to use to refer back to some earlier sections if you are not familiar with things like the vertex function or 1 particle irreducible diagrams.